# how I can get the process username

Tags: vb.net, process

I wanna get process username a try p.StartInfo.UserName but it return Empty string
I run this code from windows service because I need to know how users logon the PC from service and write Event Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function GetUserName(ByVal ProcessName As String)
        Dim selectQuery As SelectQuery = New SelectQuery("Win32_Process")
        Dim searcher As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery)
        Dim y As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection
        y = searcher.Get
        For Each proc As ManagementObject In y
            Dim s(1) As String
            proc.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", CType(s, Object()))
            Dim n As String = proc("Name").ToString()
            If n = ProcessName & ".exe" Then
                Return ("User: " & s(1) & "\\" & s(0))
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does so the OP understands. Also im sure you need to import a namespace or two you didnt mention...

Answer (score 0):

`Me.txtUser.Text = Environment.UserName`

`Me.txtDomain.Text = Environment.UserDomainName`

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.